# C# Form.Cursor set not accepting transparent cursors

Tags: c#, cursor

I'm trying to make the cursor invisible (Only want to hide the cursor on one form so `Cursor.Hide` is not an option) and the method I'm trying is to set Form.Cursor to a cursor generated using a icon with a transparent background and no content but it's not working.

I assume there are some requirements for setting the cursor like min pixel count or min size, but I can't find them if there are.

My code:

```
form.Cursor = new Cursor((new Icon("fake.ico")).Handle);
```

fake.ico is a 1x1 icon file with nothing but a transparent background in.

How do I make the cursor invisible on a single form or set the cursor to a transparent ico?

Comment: Project + Add New Item, Cursor File.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently using an ICO file handle works differently to loading it from resources, I fixed my problem by creating a new cursor (Project -> Add New Item -> Cursor) then set my cursor like so:

```
using (System.IO.Stream stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("Namespace.Cursor.cur"))
{
    form.Cursor = new Cursor(stream);
}
```

Where Namespace is your current namespace and Cursor is the name of the transparent cursor file I made.

Answer (score 0):

```
        // The following generates a cursor from an embedded resource. 

        // To add a custom cursor, create a bitmap 
        //        1. Add a new cursor file to your project:  
        //                Project->Add New Item->General->Cursor File 

        // --- To make the custom cursor an embedded resource  --- 

        // In Visual Studio: 
        //        1. Select the cursor file in the Solution Explorer 
        //        2. Choose View->Properties. 
        //        3. In the properties window switch "Build Action" to "Embedded Resources"
```

this taken from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) use this for setting a new cursor on system and then set it on form.
afterward continue as you tried before:

```
this.Cursor = new Cursor(GetType(), "[you'r cursor name]");
```

Comment: Yeah I've made my own cursor file, It's just not accepting it for some reason (If I change it to a none-transparent one it works fine).

Comment: so basically when you change it to a none-transparent you use the same format of image?